# JSON File Extension

Tags: json, jquery, file-extension

I've been saving all my json files with .txt extension and they worked with jquery ajax calls.

When I change the extension to .json and in my jquery ajax call -- **jQuery.ajax()** -- I specify

- dataType: "json",
- contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

the files no longer work. Why so?

Shouldn't all json files have an extension .json? I'm using IIS server.

**JSON**

```
{ "rows": [ 
  {"row":[ 
    {"cells": [ 
      {"data": "Edit"}, 
      {"data": "030194"} 
    ]} 
  ]}, 
  {"row":[ 
    {"cells": [ 
      {"data": "Add"}, 
      {"data": "030194"} 
    ]} 
  ]}  
]}
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery.ajax ({ 
  type: "GET", 
  url: "localhost/ABC.json", 
  dataType: "json", 
  contentType: "application/json; 
  charset=utf-8", 
  cache: "false", 
  success: function(response){}  
});
```

**Can someone please tell me why extension .json is not working? It works if I change it to .txt**

Comment: There's a decent chance that the problem is your web server. There is an even bigger chance that you are totally misusing JSON by trying to (presumably?) store data.

Comment: @Stargazer712: My money's on the web server. Unrecognized content/mime type, so a text (text/plain) no longer has a valid `Content-Type`

Comment: Thank you, Brad Christie!! I changed the mimeType to "application/x-javascript" and added ".json" extension for IIS7 using the IIS Manager. Changed my .txt files into .json and voila! it works :)

Comment: It does not matter what extension your files has as long as it works. The question is why you request actual files with ajax instead of scripts in some server side language that outputs the data.

Comment: Since this question is answered, can we close this question please?

Comment: yes, this question can be closed.

Answer (score 6):

The correct extension is `.json`, and the mime type is `application/json` (reference: [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)). Generally speaking, however, it should work with any extension so long as your data structure is valid and your web server is doing what it's supposed to.

Answer (score 4):

IIS comes bundled with a bunch of MIME type handlers. This means when you enter a URL that ends with, for example, `.png`, IIS knows that this is an image, and dispatches the appropriate response to tell the client (browser) that it's an image (so it can be rendered as such).

`.json` doesn't have a MIME type handler by default. You need to set one up:

- Load IIS Manager
- Browse the tree nodes up to your web app or website
- Double click on the MIME Types feature (lower pane)
- Click Add (RHS under "Add", or right-click and pick Add)
- Put `.txt` under the extension field and `application/json` as the MIME type

You're done! Try requesting the JSON file in the browser; if it renders correctly (as text), awesome. If not, you may have to tell IIS to render it as `text/plain` instead.

Answer (score 0):

dataType: "json"  is not to specify the type of a file is to specify the kind of data that the server will return. From the server side, for example if you are using php, you have to return the json string using the function "json_encode" so it can be accepted by dataType: "json".