# Call JSON data from External file using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm calling a external JS file having some sample JSON code, when I try to put sample json code in the file, it throws me error at ":", but when I validate that using online tools, it says as valid json. What is going wrong in this code?

Here is my code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#click').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "json.js",
            method: "GET",
            dataType: 'application/json',
            contentType: "application/json",
             success: function(result){
                  console.log(result);
             },
             error:function() {
                 alert("Error")                  
             }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

My external json.js

```
{
"data": [{      ------> throwing error at ":" as Syntax error on token ":", ; expected
    "Service": "INSTACC",

    "Create Date": "30-Jul-2016"


}, {
    "Service": "INSTACC",

    "Create Date": "30-Jul-2016"


}]

}
```

Comment: do you know that a json file has the extension of .json?

Comment: lol you are even referencing the js file on the page, why use ajax if you are referencing the file on the page?

Comment: Refer this URL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699091/json-file-extension it will suggest you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your file type to json and dataType to "json"

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#click').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "json.json",
            method: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
             success: function(result){
                  console.log(result);
             },
             error:function() {
                 alert("Error")                  
             }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry I had misplaced as .js..Still its going into error call back.

Comment: how does the xhr request body look like?

Comment: I dont need any request body.. I just need to call that external json file and load the data in success call back

Comment: and how are you doing that,aren't you doing a request for the body of the file?

Comment: we are already putting that as url right in the ajax call? Its a plain GET call to get the json data as response.

Comment: Got it.  we dont require dataType: 'application/json', this line of code

Comment: yes the dataType is incorrect it should have been json ,is your ajax working now?

Answer (score 0):

"application/json" is not a valid value for the dataType property. Change it to dataType: 'json',

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>MyDemo</title>
</head>
<body>
<button id="click">Click Me</button>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#click').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "json.js",
                method: "GET",
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function(result){
                    console.log(result);
                },
                error:function(req, status, err) {
                    console.log(req);
                    console.log(status);
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Arun Kumar why does he need a contentType?

Comment: @madalin ivascu
contentType is the type of data you're sending.

dataType is what you're expecting back from the server: json, html, text, etc. 

Sorry, as it is get request without data sent to server from client, it may be removed.